# Assigning String Value to an Array is not Working

Tags: php, arrays, string

I am currently working on an array with 2 dimensions:

```
$ary['dim1']['dim2'] = ...
```

In my Case I extract Information from an Excel file to fill the array. However if i want to assign a String value like: "123.345.654A" it is automatically getting replaced by a double. 
I've tried strval() and also putting '"'+...+'"' around the String doesn't work.

For further information, this is what the code line really looks like:

```
$ary['ncm'][$data_ary[$k_0][$v_0[9]]['NCM']] = '"'+strval($data_ary[$k_0][$v_0[9]]['NCM'])+'"';
```

The second dimension works properly and returns the String correctly.
How do I assign the same value ?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, to actually fix the problem i used this solution:

```
.... = implode(array("'",$data_ary[$k_0][$v_0[9]]['NCM'],"'"));
```

This also adds the quotation marks that are necessary.